# Spring Boot 1.5.13 - QueryDSL Query ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, querydsl

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.13 with QueryDSL and whenever I issue a call to a controller I get the following `ClassNotFoundException`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: api.model.QAddress
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:161) ~[spring-boot-devtools-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 211 common frames omitted
```

However when I check the generated package the class `QAddress` is there. How do I fix this problem?

Below are my `pom.xml` for `QueryDSL`:

```
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId> 
        </dependency>

         <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: **clean build install**

Comment: I tried that several times and the error still persists

Comment: What is your directory structure ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are building or deploying your application, just verify whether there is any warning like **invalid loc header (bad signature)** for any specific jar (in your case that might be jar related to QAddress class).

If it is showing this error for any jar, then remove that folder from .m2 repository and rebuild it, then it will download that jar again and try restarting your application.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same trouble, this issue was related to NetBeans. When I started using Intellij IDEA the issue was resolved.